# Awk's output in Perl doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: perl, awk

I'm writing a simple Perl script which is meant to output the second column of an external text file (columns one and two are separated by a comma).

I'm using AWK because I'm familiar with it.

This is my script:

```
use v5.10;
use File::Copy;
use POSIX;

$s = `awk -F ',' '\$1==500 {print \$2}' STD`;
say $s;
```

The contents of the local file "STD" is:

```
CIR,BS  
60,90
70,100
80,120
90,130
100,175
150,120
200,260
300,500
400,600
500,850
600,900
```

My output is very strange and it prints out the desired "850" but it also prints a trailer of the line and a new line too!

```
ka@man01:$ ./test.pl 
850

ka@man01:$
```

The problem isn't just printing. I need to use the variable generated by awk "i.e. the $s variable) but the variable is also being reserved with a long string and a new line!

Could you guys help?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you inlining `awk` into perl anyway?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It threw an error message when I declared $s with "chomp $s"

`Can't modify scalar chomp in scalar assignment at ./test.pl line 7, near "`awk -F ',' '\$1==500 {print \$2}' STD`;"
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: @Sobrique

I'm not an expert in Perl, so I don't know if Perl has a built-in function which can open a remote file, search it, find a string, then write it into a variable.

Comment: You've described your text file `STD` as an *external file*, a *local file*, and a *remote file*. What do you mean by all these things? Surely they can't all be true at once? Why isn't it just a file?

Comment: *"I don't know if Perl has a built-in function which can open a remote file, search it, find a string, then write it into a variable"* Well no, there is no built-in function that can do all those things at once, but Perl can do anything that awk or sed can do plus a lot more. Why are you using Perl at all if you don't like it?

Comment: What do you kean by *"the variable is also being reserved with a long string"*?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you're going down a dirty road by trying to inline `awk` into `perl` in the first place. Why not instead:

```
open ( my $input, '<', 'STD' ) or die $!;
while ( <$input> ) {
    s/\s+\z//;
    my @fields = split /,/; 
    print $fields[1], "\n" if $fields[0] == 500; 
}
```

But the likely problem is that you're not handling linefeeds, and `say` is adding an extra one. Try using `print` instead, or `chomp` on the resultant string.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Sobrique.

Regardless whether I use "say" or "print" the variable is meant to be written into an external file, and it's still shown with whitespace and new line.

Thanks for posting the suggested script. It doesn't work! As in it prints empty space.

Comment: The `split` needs to be `split /,/` or similar

Comment: @Borodin, this worked like a charm! Thank you.

Now sorry for being such a pain, why is the variable only locally signficant inside the loop? Even if I declare the "fields" variable outside the while loop, I cant get it working.

I would like to use the value of the variable outside the loop. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*perl* can do many of the things that *awk* can do. Here's something similar that replaces your entire Perl program:

```
$ perl -naF, -le 'chomp; print $F[1] if $F[0]==500' STD
850
```

The `-n` creates a `while` loop around your argument to `-e`.

The `-a` splits up each line into `@F` and `-F` lets you specify the separator. Since you want to separate the fields on a comma you use `-F,`.

The `-l` adds a newline each time you call `print`.

The `-e` argument is the program to run (with the added `while` from `-n`). The `chomp` removes the newline from the output. You get a newline in your output because you happen to use the last field in the line. The `-l` adds a newline when you print; that's important when you want to extract a field in the middle of the line.

Comment: I'm not sure that shelling out to perl is preferable to shelling out to awk!

Comment: But the OP says that they *"need to use the variable generated by awk "i.e. the $s variable)"* so this is just part of a Perl program. It sounds like they should be reading the file into a hash instead.

Comment: Why are you `chomp`ing together with `-l`?

Comment: The chomp removes the newline which doesn't belong to the last record but is merely a line separator. The -l adds a newline to whatever column you decide to print (even if it is not the last column). This is the last paragraph in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get 2 newlines:

1. the backtick operator does not remove the trailing newline from the awk output. `$s` contains `"850\n"`
2. the `say` function appends a newline to the string. You have `say "850\n"` which is the same as `print "850\n\n"`